# The magnitude of an two-stages least squares coefficient is always larger than the ordinary least squares coefficient?

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I have a hard time wrapping my head around this. I know that in case of measurement errors, the OLS estimate is biased downwards zero. Omitted variables can bias the explanatory variable of interest upwards or downwards, therefore in theory could it be the case that the 2SLS estimate is smaller than OLS?

Comment: In case you're primarily interested in the binary answer: Yes, it's possible for the estimate to be smaller or larger for the very reason you stated.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, primary answer is sufficient.